# testing acl in backend haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I want to test if path of URL is created (or diponible) in server (1 or 2) , before using backend.

now i'm using that :
use_backend apps if {path_beg -i /test/}

but what i want is :
use_backend apps if {path_beg -i {variable_path}} else use_backend apps2

someone can give some help

Comment: acl is_test   path_beg /{variable}